# POSTGRESQL : select data with where clause condition from object in json data type

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, object

I have data in database from tabel **data_for_filter** and column **src_data** (type: JSON) like this

`{"filter": {"name": "Anton", "activity": "Studying"},"primary": true, "position": 1}`

in postgresql, how I can do search query with where clause name like '%Here%' ?

i was try this query

`select src_data from data_for_filter where src_data ->> 'filter' #>> 'name' like '%Here%'`

[image: but it raised error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->>` returns a text, so you can't apply `#>>` on that. `->` returns a proper `jsonb` (or `json`) value. The `#>>` operator however requires an array, so `#>> 'name'` would lead to the next error

```
where src_data -> 'filter' ->> 'name' like '%Here%'
```

you can simplify this using:

```
where src_data #>> '{filter,name}' like '%Here%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I’m misunderstanding, you’re wanting to get the JSON object field by the key “filter”, so you’re using the incorrect operator.  Try -> ‘filter’

Here’s a reference:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: Im new on database with json data type .. hehe
btw thankyou for reference.

Comment: We're all new to something or we're doing it wrong!  Enjoy the journey!